# Script Shell to find a directory with multithreading

Tags: linux, multithreading, shell

I would try to create a script in order to find a directory avoiding timeout cause to lots of files to scan.

I try to use fork but I've read it would be better with python.

```
#/bin/sh

echo 'Directory name : '
read x

fpfunction(){
n=0

while (($n<1))
do

        #find . ! -readable -prune -type d -name $x -print
        #find . -type d -name $x 2>/dev/null
    find / -type d -name $x 2>/dev/null
        #find . -type d ! -perm -g+r,u+r,o+r -prune -o -print > $x
    n=1
done
}

fork(){
    count=0
    while (($count<1))
    do
      fpfunction &
      count=$(( count+1 ))
    done
}

fork
```

Thanks by advance

Comment: `locate` will be faster than `find`, if you have done `updatedb` recently.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to accomplish? In your code as given, you'll be invoking `find` in the background. Assuming one or more directories named `$x` exist, `find` will print their path names. However, the two functions with their loops seem to add nothing but pointless complication. You could just as well replace everything beyond line 4 with `find / -type d -name $x 2>/dev/null &`